# Package recompile after changing nls_length_semantics

Tags: oracle, character-encoding, nls

I have a database where the nls_length_semantics value has been changed from byte to char. Is it necessary to recompile all the packages that have externally accessible varchar2 based data types (for example dbms_sql)?

Comment: Was anything invalidated by the change? Also `DBA_PLSQL_OBJECT_SETTINGS` includes a column indicating the semantics in place when the package was compiled, but I don't know if it uses that at runtime, which might make stop the change invalidating but mean the package still treats passed data as bytes.

Comment: That sounds like very useful information. I suspect that changing the setting doesn't invalidate any objects, but that it is keeping the "bytes" setting. As the package is not invalid, the DBA wasn't keen to recompile it for no reason, but if I can find the entry in that table then I can show that it does need recompiling.

Answer (score 2):

@GWu is wrong in my opinion.  At least, he is wrong in spirit.  It's not a matter of WANT, it's a matter of NEED.  However, he is also correct in the sense that he says: *it depends*.

You do NEED to recompile your packages, if the underlying data in the database is multi-byte.

I've had problems today where the packages were compiled in BYTE format, although the underlying data in my tables is in Unicode.  The tables have been defined explicitly as being (for example) VARCHAR2(20 CHAR), while the code in my PL/SQL packages have only been defined as VARCHAR2(20).

This means that a column in the database defined with length 50, does not always fit into a PL/SQL variable defined as being length 50.  My users have been reporting a lot of "character buffer too small" kinds of errors as a result.

A recompile of the packages is required if you have the same case as me.

However, what I'd really like to know, is how do I know if a package was compiled in a BYTE format.  This way I would know exactly which of my packages need to be recompiled.  Without knowing this, I don't have a method of pro-actively going out there to re-compile them.  I just have to wait for the user to report the problem.

I suppose I could re-compile them all of course, but that would lock my database while users are still in it.  So I have to schedule some downtime again to fix the whole problem :-(

**--EDIT--**

Should have read comment from @AlexPoole before posting that.  The view `dba_plsql_object_settings` gives the information I need!

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: it depends :-)

If you want **your** *existing* packages to use char semantics, you need to recompile. Otherwise they will stay with the setting they had at compile time. From a technical point of view, there is no need to recompile.

And there is definitely no need to recompile SYS owned packages (like dbms_sql).

Comment: sys.htp seems to think in bytes and accepts longer strings containing "strange characters" after changing nls_length_semantics to char and recompiling it!